# How to mute all players (but friends) on PS4, for any game?

Tags: ps4

The title says all: how do I mute everybody on my PS4, for any game? And how can I then unmute only my friends?

Comment: Idk about PS4 (or Xbox One) for that matter, buuuut on Xbox360, you could create a party with your friends which effectively muted everyone that wasnt was in the party chat. Maybe PS4 has a feature like that?

Comment: I believe the PS4 has a party feature too, but I don't have friends, so... /joke